# What is the Space Complexity of Tail Recursive Quicksort?

Tags: algorithm, quicksort, partitioning, space-complexity

Looking at the following tail recursive quicksort pseudocode

```
QuickSort(A[1, ..., n], lo, hi)
Input: An array A of n distinct integers, the lower index and the higher index
         // For the first call lo = 1 and hi = n
Output: The array A in sorted order

If lo = hi return
         // The array A is already sorted in this case
If lo > hi or indices out of the range 1 to n then return

Else
      Pick an index k in [lo,hi] as the pivot
              // Assume that this can be done using O(1) cells on the stack
      i = Partition(A[lo, ..., hi], k)
              // Use in-place partitioning here so assume that this can be done
              // using O(1) space on the stack

If i - lo <= hi - i
      QuickSort(A, lo, i-1) // sort the smaller half first
      QuickSort(A, i+1, hi)
Else
      QuickSort(A, i+1, hi) // sort the smaller half first
      QuickSort(A, lo, i-1)
```

Assuming that the pivot is chosen adversarially each time I analyzed that it should have a space complexity of O(logn) [which I am not entirely sure is correct], but how would the space complexity be affected if the pivot is then chosen uniformly at random?  I am fairly new to understanding space complexity over time complexity, so any feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Refer this article covering [Tail Recursion](http://www.cs.nthu.edu.tw/~wkhon/algo08-tutorials/tutorial2b.pdf)

Within the article it says that the Space Complexity of a Tail Recursive Quick Sort is as follows:

```
space complexity = input + O(log(n))
```

A few articles to get a more in depth of understanding can be found below:

- [Pivoting To Understand QuickSort Pt.1](https://medium.com/basecs/pivoting-to-understand-quicksort-part-1-75178dfb9313)
- [Pivoting To Understand QuickSort Pt.2](https://medium.com/basecs/pivoting-to-understand-quicksort-part-2-30161aefe1d3)
- [QuickSort Notes from Duke](https://users.cs.duke.edu/~reif/courses/alglectures/skiena.lectures/lecture5.pdf)
- [Carnegie Melon Randomized Quicksort Lecture Notes](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f11/lectures/lect0906.pdf)
- [Algorithmic Analysis of QuickSort](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35994/why-does-randomized-quicksort-have-on-log-n-worst-case-runtime-cost/35995)
- [QuickSort Using Random Pivoting](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quicksort-using-random-pivoting/)

Comment: Also refer to [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38487269/space-complexity-of-quick-sort) if you are still looking for more information

Comment: The above article is all fine and dandy, but it does not explicitly state whether the pivot point is being chosen adversarially or uniformly at random, which I am assuming affects the space complexity.

Comment: For time and space complexcity there are always best and worse case scenarios. These mostly are something that differs in regards to time complexity. When it comes to space complexity this will depend on the type of partiion you use in your implementation of the quick sort. 



What I'm saying might make more since after reading the Space Complexity section in this article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).

Let me know if that helps answers your questions. @JoeCur

Comment: So then are both methods of chosing pivots O(logn) space?

Comment: From what I have been able to gather. I have found a few other article discussing the algorithm analysis of Quick Sort. Would you like those as well too read? @JoeCur

Comment: Yes, but I am not entirely sure that this is true at all.

Answer (score 0):

The worst case for time is if you divide the array as unevenly as possible, and that time will be `O(n^2)`.  If you're not doing tail-recursion, that will also be the worst case for space.

However if you divide the array unevenly and are doing a tail-recursive sort, the call to sorting the larger half takes no space because you just replace the current call frame.  Therefore the maximum space used is when you've made the first recursive calls over and over again.  Which is at most `1/2` of at most `1/2` of... for a total of `log_2(n)` call frames.

If you switch from worst case to average case with a uniformly chosen pivot, it is `O(log(n))` again, but with a better constant.  First of all it can't be more than that because the average case cannot exceed the worst case.

The trick is to prove that you can't improve that bound.  To demonstrate that, we can prove that the average space to sort an array of size `n` is at least `C log(n+1)/(3 log(2))` where `C` is the space for a single call.

By inspection this is true for `n = 1, 2, ..., 7` because the initial call takes space `C` and `log(n+1)/(3 log(2)) <= 1`.

If `n` is bigger than 7 and the statement is true up to `n`, our pivot will break us into groups of size `m` and `n-m` where `m <= n-m`.  With at least even odds, `n <= 4m` and our expected maximum cost during the first recursive call is at least

```
C 1 + f(m)
  >= C  + f(n/4 rounded up)
  >= C (3 log(2)) /(3 log(2))    + C log(n/4 + 1)/(3 log(2)))
  >  C (3 log(2)                 + log(n+1) - 2 log(2)    ) / (3 log(2)) )
   = C (log(n+1) + log(2)) / (3 log(2))
```

The rest of the time that doesn't hold and our expected maximum cost during the tail-recursive call is at least

```
f(n-m)
  >= f(n/2 rounded down)
  >= C log(n/2 + 1/2) / (3 log(2)) # n/2
   = C (log(n+1) - log(2)) / (3 log(2))
```

When you average those two, you get the desired lower bound of `C log(n+1) / (3 log(2))`.

(I may have made a small error, but the idea is right.)